# Is it possible to change timezone's scope to store?

Tags: email, localisation, timezone

After googling how to set the timezone for each Magento store I can see that there is a lot of confusion around.

All blog posts I've read confuse "website" with "store name" and "store view". A lot of guides out there tell you that one can easily change magento's timezone for each store. This left me puzzled as I'm unable to change it in mine for each store.

Indeed, the docs say that timezone has a scope of "website" http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_config/edit/general

So I gather that by default one can only change the timezone for each website, and NOT at "store name" level. This is really bad for transactional emails however.

I was wondering if anybody knows how to change the scope of the timezone setting to store name level, or any other way in which this can be achieved.

Comment: Could you please tell why do you need to set Timezone for store view scope? As Store View Scope should be used to display your shop in different languages, but not for different countries.

Comment: I do not want to change timezone for store view as I'm using that only for language variations. I want to change it for "store name" level. This is important for transactional emails, as they include the website's default time, which may not be the same in all stores as they may be set for different countries. I'll edit my question to make this clearer

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "store name" level. If you are talking about "store groups" (also referred to as "store" in the Magento admin, the level between website and store view), *nothing* can be configured on this level, except the root category.

You should probably restructure your shop to use different websites where you have store groups now.